# Excel VBA - Record when change in a cell occurred

Tags: excel, vba, record, intersect

I am not an expert in VBA and all my codes are 'found' over the internet, modified and used for my purposes, so that's why i'm struggling here.

I have very specific (yet simple) tool where, when incorrect barcodes are scanned (column B), i need to record actual time (in column V).

This tool compares scanned barcode with expected data - when error occurs,
it says what kind of error that is - this is done by queries (load expected data) and formulas (compare scanned vs expected).

To the point:

In the sheet named "Scan" users are scanning barcodes in column B.
Column C gives "OK" or error message.
Column U stays empty if B cell is empty, number 0 when "OK" or number 1 when error.

My goal:

When number 1 in column U appears - i need to write actual time when that happened into same row, into column V.

I have tried many codes with no luck.
My last (non working) is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Scan").Range("U3:U1050")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Range(.Row, 22) = Now()
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Target.Row, 22) = Now()`.

Comment: That really should be `Cells`, not `Range`.

Comment: Yep, cells work, yet still not giving me date or Now().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want the date only if column U shows 1. In all other cases Column V should be empty. And any changes should be ignored except for changes in column U.
But since column U contains a formula referring to column B, you should activate the procedure if column B changes. Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 2 Then
    With Target.EntireRow
      If .Cells(21).Value = 1 Then
        .Cells(22).Value = Now()
      Else
        .Cells(22).Value = Empty
      End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For code or manual input it works very well, but not for formula. 
I have a formula there, these columns will be hidden for users - they will be able to edit only column B. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now it looks for changes in column B. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hello, tried just now. Still ignores change of formula output.

Comment: Seems like your code should work with some modification. So i have tried to modify it (in test sheet) to first put value of formula to next cell and then compare, it does not even copy/paste it:  
          .Cells(3) = Cells(2).Value

Comment: What is the formula in column U?

Comment: =IF(B4="";"";IF(E4="0";1;IF(AND(E4="1";R4=1);0;IF(AND(E4="1";R4>1);1;IF(AND(E4="2";R4=1);0;IF(AND(E4="2";R4>1);1;1))))))

Seems difficult, but gives only 0 or 1

Comment: That means the formula depends on columns B, E and R. So change the 2nd line to: `IF Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 5 Or Target.Column = 18`

Comment: Still nothing. Only hard input is in column B - no formulas there. All other columns have formulas (i need to compare many data and evaluate output). 
I just remembered my first testing. Seems that formulas are much faster than VBA in this case. As such, once user will input data (via scanner) into column B, all formulas are calculated. 
Now important note - only column B is unlocked, all others are locked. So once data are input in cell in column B, next line is activated. 
Now i think VBA will calculate actual line - empty - not the one before, or active at the time of input.

Comment: In this case `If Target.Column = 2 Then` should be sufficient. `Target.EntireRow` is the row that had a change. It has nothing to do with the activated cell. Do you know how to work with breakpoints and the Watches window? You can put a breakpoint on the second line and put `Target.Colum` in the Watches window. Then scan a new barcode and watch what column number has changed.

Comment: OK, your code works well. I've had it under "ThisWorkbook", not under the sheet "Scan" where it was supposed to be.
Now it works fine. Many, many thanks for your help!

Have a great day!